# How could I default a date column as 21 days ahead of another date column in oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, datetime, create-table

Here is my table (with the working columns including primary key removed for simplicity)

```
 CREATE TABLE loans
    (checkout_date DATE,
     due_date DATE DEFAULT 'checkout_date' + 21,
     )
```

This code returns "ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected DATE got NUMBER".
With '21' instead returns the same error.
Any help is appreciated!

Comment: probably would need a trigger for that. but   I would probably suggest doing that in the code, or if it is always 21 days ahead just make a view

Comment: `'checkout_date'` is a string. By applying `+ 21` you make Oracle think that the string contains a number that is to be added to 21. Hence the error "expected DATE got NUMBER".

Comment: The accepted answer suggests that you never wanted a `DEFAULT` (that is used when inserting a row without specifying a value for the column), but a computed column (directly or via a view). Make sure you understand the difference for future situations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that Oracle supports setting a default from another column. One workaround would be to use a trigger, but that might be overkill here. Why not just put the logic in a view?

```
create view v_loans as 
select checkout_date, coalesce(due_date, checkout_date + 21) as due_date from loans
```

Or we can get a little fancy with a computed column:

```
create table loans (
    checkout_date date,
    due_date      date,
    real_due_date date as (coalesce(due_date, checkout_date + 21))
);
```

Then you would use column `real_due_date` instead of `due_date` in your queries.

For the whole thing to make more sense, you would probably need a `not null` constraint on column `checkout_date`.

Side note: as commented by mathghy and Thorsten Kettner, this does not strictly implements the concept of `DEFAULT`, because, even if a `NULL` value is explictely assign to the column, the view (and the computed column) would still apply the replacement logic (which a `DEFAULT` would not do).

Comment: Yeah I don't think oracle does after a lot of looking around. Thanks a lot ill have a play with these solutions.

Comment: I think you are confused about the meaning of "default". In an `insert` statement, the default is used only if no value is provided for that column - the column is not included in the list of the `insert` statement. If `null` is provided for the column, then the value **will** be `null`, the default is not used for that situation. You can't do that with a view. In my opinion this answer is entirely wrong; downvote from me.

Comment: @mathguy: I do understand the concept of default. My experience on SO taught the we sometimes need to read between the lines of what OPs are asking, rather than following a strict interpretation - for what it's worth, it turns out OP accepted this answer. I still edited, to be more descriptive about how this does not behave exactly like `DEFAULT` in all cases (I would agree that this piece of information was missing in my answer to start with).

Comment: Right - so we are in agreement: if you make the assumption that the OP meant something other than what he asked, you should make that clear at the top of your answer. As to the OP accepting the answer and this proving something (*anything*), let's not get into that... :-)

Comment: I ended up creating a view instead which works fine for what i'm trying to do, Thanks guys some useful info here!